# Getting Error (1,-2147483648) in AndroidMedia Player while playing 3gp file from external storage which is first recorded using MediaRecorder

Tags: android, android-studio, android-mediaplayer, android-mediarecorder

Getting  E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648) while trying to play android `MediaPlayer` . Permission is granted , file format is 3gp . I have been trying to apply answer given to this topic in my code but nothing solve the issue.

```
   player = new MediaPlayer();
            File file = new File(filePath);
            file.setReadable(true,false);
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
            player.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());

            inputStream.close();

            player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                        mp.start();
                        flag=true;
                }


            });
            player.prepareAsync();
```

Comment: which android version are you to run the application? [media format supported by android](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/media-formats)

Comment: i have tried it in api 22,19,27

Answer (score 0):

change sequence of the line as below

```
player = new MediaPlayer();
File file = new File(filePath);
file.setReadable(true,false);
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
player.setDataSource(inputStream.getFD());

inputStream.close();
player.prepareAsync();

player.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mp.start();
            flag=true;
    }


});
```